# Accessing multiple dynamic controls values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic-controls

I am adding multiple controls dynamically based on a dropdownlist that the user selects. i.e. if the user selects 3 then 3 sets of the controls are added. My problem is not in adding the controls, I can add them fine, I haven't added all my code but the main parts to understand what I am doing.

Once the controls have been created, the relevant info is captured. On the Update click I need to access the values of these dynamic controls by looping through in the correct order and retrieve the values and write to the database. I can't seem to access them correctly.

Hopefully I am making sense. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
''Loop through first set of controls and get values and then the next set etc..

Dim Description as string = ''Get Textbox value
Dim Type as string = ''Get RadComboBox value
Dim XFieldName as string = ''Get RadComboBox value
Dim Colour as string = ''Get RadColorPicker value
```

Below is my Code:

VB

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    RecreateControlsTxt("txt", "TextBox")
    RecreateControlsChart("comboChart", "RadComboBox")
    RecreateControls("combo", "RadComboBox")
    RecreateControlsCP("cp", "RadColorPicker")

End Sub

Protected Sub AddControls_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddControls.Click

    For i As Integer = 0 To ddlFieldNames.SelectedIndex
        CreateTextbox("txt-" & Convert.ToString(i + 1))
    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To ddlFieldNames.SelectedIndex
        CreateComboChart("comboChart-" & Convert.ToString(i + 1))
    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To ddlFieldNames.SelectedIndex
        CreateComboField("combo-" & Convert.ToString(i + 1))
    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To ddlFieldNames.SelectedIndex
        CreateColourPicker("cp-" & Convert.ToString(i + 1))
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub CreateTextbox(ByVal ID As String)
    Dim txt As New TextBox()
    txt.ID = ID
    txt.Height = 20
    Me.divDesc.Controls.Add(txt)
End Sub

Private Sub CreateComboField(ByVal ID As String)
    Dim combo As New RadComboBox()
    combo.ID = ID
    combo.DataSource = Me.odsChartsSeriesField
    combo.DataTextField = "FieldNames"
    combo.DataValueField = "FieldNames"
    combo.DataBind()
    Me.divField.Controls.Add(combo)
End Sub

Private Sub CreateComboChart(ByVal ID As String)
    Dim comboChart As New RadComboBox()
    comboChart.ID = ID
    Dim item1 As New RadComboBoxItem()
    item1.Text = "Line"
    item1.Value = "smoothedLine"
    item1.ImageUrl = ("Images/linechart.png")
    comboChart.Items.Add(item1)
    Dim item2 As New RadComboBoxItem()
    item2.Text = "Column"
    item2.Value = "column"
    item2.ImageUrl = ("Images/bar chart.png")
    comboChart.Items.Add(item2)
    Dim item3 As New RadComboBoxItem()
    item3.Text = "Pie"
    item3.Value = "pie"
    item3.ImageUrl = ("Images/pie chart.jpg")
    comboChart.Items.Add(item3)
    Me.divChart.Controls.Add(comboChart)
End Sub

Private Sub CreateColourPicker(ByVal ID As String)
    Dim cp As New RadColorPicker()
    cp.ID = ID
    cp.ShowIcon = True
    cp.Style("padding-top") = "1px"
    cp.CssClass = "CustomHeight"
    Me.divCol.Controls.Add(cp)
End Sub

Protected Sub Update_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Update.Click
    Try
            Dim alltxt = divDesc.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
            Dim allcomboChart = divChart.Controls.OfType(Of RadComboBox)()
            Dim allcomboField = divField.Controls.OfType(Of RadComboBox)()
            Dim allcp = divCol.Controls.OfType(Of RadColorPicker)()

            ''Loop through first set of controls and get values and then the next etc..
            Dim Description as string = ''Get Textbox value
            Dim Type as string = ''Get RadComboBox value
            Dim XFieldName as string = ''Get RadComboBox value
            Dim Colour as string = ''Get RadColorPicker value

            If Page.IsValid Then
                Dim da As New dsSVTableAdapters.Chart
                Dim Result As String = da.Series(60, Description, Type, Colour, "YFieldName", XFieldName)
            End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblResult.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `Description = alltxt.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.ID = "txt-0").Text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a repeated set of controls. Therefore you need a corresponding repeated set of variables that store these values.
I suggest creating a class where you can store a variable (or property) set.

```
Public Class ControlSet
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property XFieldName As String
    Public Property Colour As String
End Class
```

Create an array that holds these values

```
Dim Values = New ControlSet(ddlFieldNames.SelectedIndex) {}
```

And retrieve the values in a loop

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Values.Length - 1
    Values(i).Description = CType(divDesc.FindControl("txt-" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)), TextBox).Text
    Values(i).Type = CType(divChart.FindControl("comboChart-" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)), RadComboBox).SelectedValue
    Values(i).XFieldName = ...
    ...
Next
```

Also use the ID of the control; this helps to avoid confusion in case you have several controls of the same type.

Comment: Thanks @Olivier Jacot-Descombes, your method seems ideal. However when I step through the loop to access the controls values, I receive divDesc = {InnerText = (InnerText) threw an exception of type System.Web.HttpException.}" It's not getting the values for some reason, The divs are within a panel if that will makes any difference.Thank you

Comment: The value of a `TextBox` has to be accessed through the `Text` property. see [RadControls for Silverlight](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radcombobox-features-selection.html) for an explanation of how to access the value of the `RadComboBox` (I never used it). `InnerText` is used to access a Html literal.

Comment: I managed to get it working by accessing the control value with:                    `Dim vDescription As TextBox = DirectCast(divDesc.FindControl("txt-" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)), TextBox)
                    Dim Description = vDescription.Text` thanks

Comment: Yes, `DirectCast` is better than `CType` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.FindControl(string id)` method, and you should keep the controls count in your view state or session:

```
Protected Sub Update_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Update.Click
Try
        ''Loop through first set of controls and get values and then the next etc..
        For i As Integer = 0 To controlsCount - 1
            Dim Description as string = ((TextBox)divDesc.FindControl("txt-" & Convert.ToString(i + 1))).Text ''Get Textbox value
            Dim Type as string = ((RadComboBox)divChart.FindControl("comboChart-" & Convert.ToString(i + 1))).SelectedValue ''Get RadComboBox value
            Dim XFieldName as string = ((RadComboBox)divField.FindControl("combo-" & Convert.ToString(i + 1))).SelectedValue ''Get RadComboBox value
            Dim Colour as string = ((RadColorPicker)divField.FindControl("cp-" & Convert.ToString(i + 1))).SelectedValue ''Get RadColorPicker value

            If Page.IsValid Then
                Dim da As New dsSVTableAdapters.Chart
                Dim Result As String = da.Series(60, Description, Type, Colour, "YFieldName", XFieldName)
        Next
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblResult.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```